# When trying to build appleseed on linux against newly built llvm lib i get this error. Any possible fix?

Tags: build, llvm

```
[100%] Building CXX object src/appleseed.studio/CMakeFiles/appleseed.studio.dir/qrc_resources.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable appleseed.studio
/usr/bin/ld: /home/geck/gsoc_testing/prebuilt-linux-deps/lib/liboslexec.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for llvm::SectionMemoryManager'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/geck/gsoc_testing/prebuilt-linux-deps/lib/liboslexec.so: undefined reference to `llvm::DisableABIBreakingChecks'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/geck/gsoc_testing/prebuilt-linux-deps/lib/liboslexec.so: undefined reference to `llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(std::string const&, std::string&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/geck/gsoc_testing/prebuilt-linux-deps/lib/liboslexec.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for llvm::raw_ostream'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/appleseed.studio/CMakeFiles/appleseed.studio.dir/build.make:3739: src/appleseed.studio/appleseed.studio] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:717: src/appleseed.studio/CMakeFiles/appleseed.studio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

all the other libraries are prebuilt, i just removed llvm libs and headers from the prebuilt folder and I built it locally, it fails at the linking process